# Switching 230V load once every second

Tags: relay, switching

So I build a binary clock with led's as outputs. And now it has been suggest to me, that I should make it bigger and use lightbulbs instead of led's. At first I thought I would just use relays, but then I remember they have a limited number of times they can switch.  Is there any other element I could use (transistor,...) that would work the same and what would be adjoining circuit.

Comment: Triacs or SSRs come to mind, but you can easily find low-ish DC LED assemblies (LED strips and so on, for both constant voltage and constant current driving) that are as powerful as lightbulbs.

Comment: It's good to use a triac and a zero-cross optoisolator triac driver such as MOC3043, completely replaces the relay.

Comment: lightbulbs also won't last long if switched on and off every second.

Comment: If you just want a bigger/cooler version of your clock, you can beat the efficiency of lightbulbs with the DC high power LED option, and they also don't mind fast switching.